# Android :-Consume a web service through Post method as a json Request and Response

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, wcf

My web service code is following  i am using WCF Restful webservices,

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
      UriTemplate = "Login?parameter={parameter}")]
      string Login(string parameter);


 public string Login(string parameter)
    {



        /*
         * input :=  {"username":"kevin","password":"123demo"}
         * output:=  1=sucess,0=fail
         *
        */

        //Getting Parameters from Json  
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(parameter);
        string username = (string)jo["username"];
        string password = (string)jo["password"];
        return ""+username;
}
```

my client side(Android) code is following

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          try {
            json.put("username","demo");
            json.put("password","password123");

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter",""+json.toString()));
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
        Log.i("response", ""+response.toString());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        string=responseText;
        Log.i("Output", ""+responseText);
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("Exception", ""+e);
        }
```

I am getting following output after calling Web service:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server
>   logs for more details.

Basically my problem is I am unable to pass value by using `NameValuePair`.

Comment: Try to inspect the raw request and see what is wrong with your request that is causing the problem. Also enable Tracing on your Service to know the exact details of the error.

Comment: @Rajesh Actually i debug raw request on server but its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me:

```
 public static String getJsonData(String webServiceName,String parameter)
{  
    try  
    {
    String urlFinal=SERVICE_URI+"/"+webServiceName+"?parameter=";
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlFinal.trim()+""+URLEncoder.encode(parameter,"UTF-8"));
    postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
    Log.i("response", ""+response.toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    string=responseText;
    Log.i("Output", ""+responseText);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
    }

return string;
}
```